# Error while creating MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql

```
create procedure proc_Grade(in roll int(5),in name varchar(20),in marks int(5))
-> begin
-> declare grade varchar(20);
-> insert into student values(roll,name,marks);
-> if marks<=100 and marks>=67 then set grade="distinction";
-> if marks<=66 and marks>=57 then set grade="firstclass";
-> if marks<=56 and marks>=47 then set grade="secdclass";
-> if marks<=46 and marks>=40 then set grade="pass";
-> else set grade="fail";
-> insert into result values(roll,grade);
-> end if;
-> end$$
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 12

[Here's a screenshot of command line client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjJX8.png)

Comment: It sounds like you forgot `delimiter $$` at the first line

Comment: Even after doing that I'm getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure you want to add  `else set grade="fail"`? it will set "fail" on more records then you expect.

Comment: Yes it's required

Comment: @kunaldeshpande: you have to execute `delimiter $$` before `create procedure` statement? can you post screenshot of your mysql client with error stack displayed.

Comment: okay I've added the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

As error messages go, that one is particularly unhelpful.

There are two remaining issues:

1. The position of the second insert statement (result) which will only run for students who 'fail' the course.
2. The **IF** statement syntax where the second, and subsequent, **IF** should be **ELSEIF** or you should terminate each **IF** statement with **END IF**;

The syntax should be in the form

```
IF condition1 THEN
  statement1;
ELSEIF condition2 THEN
  statement2;
END IF;
```

The documentation is at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html (though watch out for the typo which misses the semi-colon after END IF;)

Your procedure would look like this:

```
delimiter $$

create procedure proc_Grade(in roll int(5),in name varchar(20),in marks int(5))
begin
  declare grade varchar(20);

  insert into student values(roll,name,marks);

  if marks<=100 and marks>=67 then 
    set grade="distinction";
  elseif marks<=66 and marks>=57 then
    set grade="firstclass";
  elseif marks<=56 and marks>=47 then
    set grade="secdclass";
  elseif marks<=46 and marks>=40 then
    set grade="pass";
  else
    set grade="fail";
  end if;

  insert into result values(roll,grade);

end $$
```

Comment: The error message is a MySQL quirk but still helpful, if you know what it means: unexpected thing found **next** in the parse buffer: `...near 'unexpected thing' at line...`. An empty string in the error means there is nothing left to parse, i.e. the parser ran out of tokens in a state when it simply can't be possible that your statement is complete. Here, the parser expected the last `END` to be followed by `IF`, not nothing. (The delimiter is already not in the parse buffer because the CLI actually strips it.) `SELECT * FROM;` or `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE;` would generate the same error.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, thanks for that contribution, a very clear explanation.